# how to send json data to serializable class

Tags: javascript, .net, json, dojo, serializable

there is a problem when send json data to serializable class. On client side when i check data on browser it is true but on server side the fields of serializable class are null.

Client side (using dojo) : on the debugger line fileds of ticket object are assigned

```
var Ticket = {
        ProductId: productId,
        Type: ticketType
    };

    DataService.xhrPageMethodJson("api/Tickets/MyTickets"
        , dojo.toJson(Ticket)
        , {
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                loadSubPage(getRoot("Support/Tickets.aspx?mode=list"));
            },
            error: function (err) {
                LoadingOverlay.hide();
            }
        });
```

Web Method: On this method ticket.ProductId, ticket.Type fields has default value or null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [ActionName("MyTickets")]
    [Authorize]
    public void MyTickets([FromBody]Ticket ticket)
    {
        DataTable myTickets = db.Tickets.MyTickets(Globals.LogonUser.User.Id, ticket.ProductId, ticket.Type);
        WebContext.Session["Tickets"] = myTickets;
    }
```

Ticket class:

```
[Serializable]
[EntityTable(Name = "Tickets")]
public class Ticket : Entity
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(User), "Id")]
    public int SenderUserId { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(Product), "Id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(TicketImportanceLevel), "Id")]
    public int ImportanceLevel { get; set; }
    public int Analyze { get; set; }
    public int SolutionTransactionId { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(TicketType), "Id")]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int AssignedUserId { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem with marking properties as data member and class as data contract. Here I am sharing  new class structure:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[EntityTable(Name = "Tickets")]
public class Ticket : Entity
{
    [DataMember]
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(User), "Id")]
    [DataMember]
    public int SenderUserId { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(Product), "Id")]
    [DataMember]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(TicketImportanceLevel), "Id")]
    [DataMember]
    public int ImportanceLevel { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Analyze { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int SolutionTransactionId { get; set; }
    [JoinField(typeof(TicketType), "Id")]
    [DataMember]
    public int Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int AssignedUserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float Score { get; set; }
}
```